# windows git ssh connection time out

Tags: git

After I generated .ssh folder and SSH key I tried to connect to github using command `ssh -T git@github.com`. But it showed "ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Connection timed out". I thought it probably because the port is not available. So I switch the port number to 443 by created a config file. Content as below:

```
Host github.com
User myEmail@xxx.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile .ssh/id_rsa
Port 443
```

But it not working, Error: ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection timed out
Could anyone can explain to me how can I fix this problem? BTW, I can connect to the github with Chrome, but if I ping github.com or any other website the time out will come.

Comment: Any other websites like google or amazon ping worked in your command line?

Comment: "*I can connect to the github with Chrome*" This means protocol HTTPS works in your network so use it instead of SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. windows(7/10) firewall check
   inbound / outbound
   port : 443, 22
2. router firewall check
   IP address is written in the router manual 192.168.x.x

Comment: Sorry for reply late. My problem was solved. It is because the proxy firewall protocol limitation. Thank you for your help.